# Changing the color and styling of the Button in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter2.0

I have migrated to Flutter 2.0 which is just the new release now. In my project I have used `Flat Buttons` but it got deprecated now in Flutter 2.0 and the suggestion pop up to use `Text Button` instead of `Flat Buttons`.

Now the problem is in `Flat Buttons` there are option directly to set the properties of button such as `color, padding etc.` but when I replaced it with `Text Button` there is error in using this properties. I have checked the documentation and found that there is the property of `style: ButtonStyle(backgroundcolor: ____________)`. But when I have put `Colors.blue` in the `backgroundcolor` property it gives me error.

So I want to know that how is the behaviour of `Buttons` in Flutter 2.0 and how we can `style` the `Buttons`?

My snippet of code is here in which I want to style the button.

```
Container(
                  width: 200.0,
                  child: TextButton(
                    style: ButtonStyle(), // I want to style this.
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, SignupPage.id),
                    /*color: Colors.blue,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),*/ //Commented code is deprecated in Flutter 2.0
                    child: Text(
                      'Create Account',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.0),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `style` argument with a `backgroundcolor` is the way to do it, but does not take a `Color` object, its type is `MaterialStateProperty<Color?>?` so you should provide an object of that type.

documentation is here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextButton-class.html
and here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ButtonStyle-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Buttons now have a state, so you have to define the colors for each state:

- you can define one color for all the states.

  ButtonStyle(
  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green),
- you can define a different color for each state.

  ButtonStyle(
  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
  (Set states) {
  if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed))
  return Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary.withOpacity(0.5);
  return null; // Use the component's default.
  },
  ),
  ),

Answer (score 0):

`ButtonStyle` does not accept simple properties like color, padding etc. It accepts something called as `MaterialStateProperty` which, if confusing, there is a convenient alternative method called `styleForm`, which accepts above mentioned simple parameters and converts them internally into `MaterialStateProperty`. You can use the method as shown below:

```
TextButton(
    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xff777777)
    ),
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Text("Change The World")
)
```

Refer to this for more properties accepted by the `styleForm` method: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextButton/styleFrom.html